# Conversion from GMT to CST showing 7 hrs difference

Tags: java

I have taken this date "2016-04-26 12:00:00”, and converted to GMT and CST epochs, using the function below. I got the dates below. Not sure I am doing anything wrong here.

```
    1461672000000 UTC ——> Tue, 26 Apr 2016 12:00:00 GMT
    1461690000000  CST —> Tue, 26 Apr 2016 17:00:00 GMT
```

Code:

```
long epoch = 0;
String str = "2016-04-26 12:00:00";  
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));  //This GMT or CST
Date datenew = df.parse(str); //parsethe date
epoch = datenew.getTime(); //get the epoch time
```

Comment: What's the problem here?  12:00 GMT = 17:00 (5 PM) CST, which is a 5 hour difference (expected result).

Comment: Your call to `getTime()` is going to store the time against UTC (because January 1 1970 midnight UTC is **epoch**).

Comment: It's not clear what your sample output is ("I got the dates below."), or even if it's really output from a program. Post an [SSCCE.](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: GMT is 5 hrs ahead of CST. In my case CST is 5 hrs ahead of GMT by 5 hrs.

Comment: 1461690000000  is five hours after 1461672000000. Again, your question isn't clear. Post an SSCCE.

Comment: For example my input date to my program is follows: 

String str = "2016-04-26 10:00:00";  

The output epoch times from my program.
1461664800000 UTC —>  Tue, 26 Apr 2016 10:00:00 GMT
1461682800000 CST —>  Tue, 26 Apr 2016 15:00:00 GMT

Comment: Ideally the GMT time = CST time + 5hrs. But in my case  CST = UTC + 5 hrs. which is wrong isn't it?

Comment: Do you see the "GMT" at the end of *both* of your time stamps? That's there because it's printing the time adjusted for GMT timezone in both cases. There's nothing about a time zone in a `Date` instance, regardless how you parsed it. And the time created when parsing with CST is 5 hours after parsing the same string with time zone set to GMT. Which is exactly correct.

Comment: Apologies; I had the conversion wrong in my initial comment.  Hopefully the answer clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As eluded to by Erickson in the comments, your expectations seem inverted from the implementation; when you set the *TimeZone* in the *DateFormat*, using the **DateFormat.parse()** method results in the **string it's parsing as if it is coming from that *TimeZone*** (and converts it to the local time).  So the results you notice are exactly expected.

To fix this, use the **DateFormat.format()** method instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateStr = "2016-04-26 12:00:00";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    Date gmtDate = null;
    try {
        gmtDate = df.parse(dateStr);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("GMT TIME = " + df.format(gmtDate));
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
    System.out.println("CST TIME = " + df.format(gmtDate));
}
```

Output:

```
GMT TIME = 2016-04-26 12:00:00
CST TIME = 2016-04-26 07:00:00
```